# Ler Array fora do foreach

Tags: php

Nesse script a baixo eu leio um array dentro do foreach, mais como eu posso ler ele fora? quando eu dou um echo ele só me retorna 1 id

```
 $data = unserialize ($linha["range_ids"]); 
 // a:3:{i:1052;s:4:"1052";i:1053;s:4:"1053";i:1054;s:4:"1054";}

 foreach($data as $key => $value): //Ler a Variavel 
  echo      $range = $key.',';  // Retorno do echo 1052,1053,1054, 
 endforeach; 

 echo $range; // Retorno do echo 1054   (Preciso que retorne assim 1052,1053,1054)
```

Comment: Acho que o loop não é necessário nesse caso. Veja a minha resposta como você pode fazer com implode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples, utiliza-se uma forma mais fácil de realizar o foreach no array.

```
$lista = array('1052','1053','1054');
$a = "";
foreach($lista as $b){
 $a .= $b . ',';
}
echo $a; // Resultado: 1052,1053,1054
```

[Consulte o Guia PHP: Array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php)

Comment: deu erro Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Comment: Erro no seu foreach. Deveria ser `foreach($lista as $b)`

Answer (score 2):

Para fazer isso utilize a função `print_r`.

exemplo:

```
$meu_array = array(1, 2, 3);

print_r($_POST);

print_r($meu_array); // Array (3) { 1, 2, 3 }
```

Você também pode usar a função `implode`

```
echo implode(',', array(1, 2, 3)); // Imprime 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Ola amigo desculpa não expliquei direito alterei la no script.  O meu array esta retornando via unserialize quando eu lei dentro do foreach que vem 1052,1053,1054 atá ai esta correto só não consigo passa esse resultado pra fora.

Answer (score 1):

A variavel `$range` esta a ter o valor sobreposto cada vez que o foreach corre.

O que parece que precisas é de acrescentar ao valor já existente, algo como isto:

```
$range = "";

foreach($data as $key => $value):
  echo      $range = $range + $key.',';  
 endforeach; 

 echo $range;
```

Comment: Ola amigo desculpa não expliquei direito alterei la no script. O meu array esta retornando via unserialize quando eu lei dentro do foreach que vem 1052,1053,1054 atá ai esta correto só não consigo passa esse resultado pra fora

Comment: Não sei se vai dar muito certo misturar soma com concatenação. Vou testar isso aqui na linha de comando

Comment: Esqueci que era PHP e nao se usa o '+' para concatenação, devia ser um ponto ali

Comment: Mesmo assim funciona, @Diogo. O PHP é doido assim mesmo